# LDAP Client setup issue: Failed to ssh into oracle linux vm using LDAP user

Tags: ldap, openldap

My LDAP configs look like:

VM running on os: Oracle Linux Server release 8.x

```
$ sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/nslcd.conf
uid nslcd
gid ldap
uri ldap://ldap.local.{company}.com/
base dc={company},dc=com

[19:14:23 Tue Jun 06]{company}{cpmpany}-centos ~
$ sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
auth        sufficient                           pam_ldap.so
auth        required                                     pam_env.so
auth        required                                     pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_localuser.so
auth        sufficient                                   pam_unix.so nullok
auth        [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok]         pam_usertype.so isregular
auth        sufficient                                   pam_sss.so{cpmpany}_pass
auth        required                                     pam_deny.so
account     required                                     pam_unix.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient                                   pam_usertype.so issystem
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account     required                                     pam_permit.so
password    requisite                                    pam_pwquality.so local_users_only
password    sufficient                                   pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok use_authtok
password    sufficient                                   pam_sss.so use_authtok
password    required                                     pam_deny.so
session     optional                                     pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required                                     pam_limits.so
-session    optional                                     pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore]                   pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required                                     pam_unix.so
session     optional                                     pam_sss.so
[19:14:33 Tue Jun 06]{company}{cpmpany}-centos ~

$ sudo grep -v -E '^\s*(#|$)' /etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:     files ldap
group:      files ldap
netgroup:   sss files
automount:  sss files
services:   sss files
shadow:     files sss
hosts:      files dns myhostname
aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files

##############################################  
### Issue: Unable to ssh using LDAP user ####
##############################################  

$ ssh nagarjunav@localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:MEVAYjZGUpFM4AC3J37X9k5XqcBpMkw0KRRh3hOOJEc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
nagarjunav@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
nagarjunav@localhost's password:

[1]+  Stopped                 ssh nagarjunav@localhost
[19:09:28 Tue Jun 06]{company}{cpmpany}-centos ~

$ id nagarjunav
uid=10279(nagarjunav) gid=10293(nagarjunav) groups=10293(nagarjunav),10007(confluence-users),10008(jira-users),10024(fn-employee)
[19:09:37 Tue Jun 06]{company}{cpmpany}-centos ~

$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ldap.local.{company}.com -D "uid=nagarjunav,ou=People,dc={company},dc=com" -W -b "dc={company},dc=com" uid=nagarjunav
Enter LDAP Password:
dn: uid=nagarjunav,ou=People,dc={company},dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
cn: nagarjunav
sn: Veer
uid: nagarjunav
uidNumber: 10279
gidNumber: 10293
homeDirectory: /home/nagarjunav
loginShell: /bin/bash
gecos: nagarjunav
givenName: Nagarjuna
mail: nagarjunav@{company}.com
displayName: Nagarjuna Veer
userPassword:: XXX=

[19:10:04 Tue Jun 06]{company}{cpmpany}-centos ~
$ ldapwhoami -x -H ldap://ldap.local.{company}.com -D "uid=nagarjunav,ou=People,dc={company},dc=com" -W
Enter LDAP Password:
dn:uid=nagarjunav,ou=People,dc={company},dc=com
[19:10:28 Tue Jun 06]{company}{cpmpany}-centos ~
```

From my oracle  I am vm able to get LDAP user informing, able to talk to LDAP server but unable to SSH into vm using LDAP user. Can someone help what i'm missing here ?

Error is: Permission denied, please try again.

Performed below connectivity tests and they look goos

- ping ldap.local.{company}.com
- socat /dev/null TCP:10.x.x.x:22
- telnet 10.x.x.x 22
- telnet ldap.local.{company}.com 389

Comment: You need to sort out whether this is an LDAP problem or an SSH problem. Off topic.

Comment: Never mind, i was able to follow instructions at https://www.golinuxcloud.com/ldap-client-rhel-centos-8/#:~:text=ca.cert.pem-,3.%20Configure%20LDAP%20client%20to%20authenticate%20with%20LDAP%20server%20using%20SSSD,-Create%20a%20new that worked.